# SWRevealViewController not opening menu

Tags: ios, swift

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98Oto.png)I am following an [Appcoda](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/) tutorial for using this library but when I try implement it, my main view opens but my bar button wont open the menu. any ideas?

```
if self.revealViewController() != nil {
    menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
    menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
}
```

Comment: Is the code inside the braces even executed? Put a breakpoint on the second line to find out.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth this is inside of me ViewDidLoad method. And yes, it goes into the if statement.

Comment: @SantiGS Are your segues setup correctly in the storyboard with the proper sw_rear and sw_front identifiers?

Comment: @SantiGS Also are you sure your menu button outlet is hooked up right?  Like if you swipe right across the view does it open your menu correctly? Because if so it would mean it's a problem with your button.  If the swipe doesn't work then it's a problem with making the SWRevealController work correctly.

Comment: @Delimiter yes, I also downloaded the finished tutorial code and mine is setup identically. But for some reason it wont "slide" into the menu.

Comment: @Delimiter I added some pictures of how my storyboard is setup.

Comment: @SantiGS can you add your code in git repo to review it?

Comment: @SantiGS Do you have #import "SWRevealViewController.h" in your bridging header? Also is your initial view controller (the one on the very left of the storyboard) have SWRevealViewController set as its class?